# Cakephp: Spurious login message

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I do not have a users login page in Cakephp(I have another login page and associated controller that works fine)
Every so often, especially if I have not used the app for a while I get a message stating that my users/login page is missing.
I have searched within the text of all files in my subdirectory, but am at a loss as to where this message originates.

Any ideas?

```
You must be logged in to view this page.
Missing Controller

Error: UsersController could not be found.

Error: Create the class UsersController below in file: app\Controller\UsersController.php

<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {

}

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\missing_controller.ctp

**Stack Trace**

    APP\webroot\index.php line 111 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)

    $Dispatcher->dispatch(

        new CakeRequest(),

        new CakeResponse()

    );

    object(CakeRequest) {
        params => array(
            'plugin' => null,
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'named' => array(),
            'pass' => array()
        )
        data => array()
        query => array()
        url => 'users/login'
        base => '/checks'
        webroot => '/checks/'
        here => '/checks/users/login'
        [protected] _detectors => array(
            'get' => array(
                'env' => 'REQUEST_METHOD',
                'value' => 'GET'
            ),
            'post' => array(
                'env' => 'REQUEST_METHOD',
                'value' => 'POST'
            ),
            'put' => array(
                'env' => 'REQUEST_METHOD',
                'value' => 'PUT'
            ),
            'delete' => array(
                'env' => 'REQUEST_METHOD',
                'value' => 'DELETE'
            ),
            'head' => array(
                'env' => 'REQUEST_METHOD',
                'value' => 'HEAD'
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'env' => 'REQUEST_METHOD',
                'value' => 'OPTIONS'
            ),
            'ssl' => array(
                'env' => 'HTTPS',
                'value' => (int) 1
            ),
            'ajax' => array(
                'env' => 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH',
                'value' => 'XMLHttpRequest'
            ),
            'flash' => array(
                'env' => 'HTTP_USER_AGENT',
                'pattern' => '/^(Shockwave|Adobe) Flash/'
            ),
            'mobile' => array(
                'env' => 'HTTP_USER_AGENT',
                'options' => array(
                    [maximum depth reached]
                )
            ),
            'requested' => array(
                'param' => 'requested',
                'value' => (int) 1
            )
        )
        [protected] _input => ''
    }
```

Appcontroller code follows:

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

/**
 * Application Controller
 *
 * Add your application-wide methods in the class below, your controllers
 * will inherit them.
 *
 * @package     app.Controller
 * @link        http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller
 */
class AppController extends Controller {

    // added the debug toolkit
    // sessions support
    // authorization for login and logut redirect
    public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'instructors', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'instructors', 'action' => 'login'),
            'authError' => 'You must be logged in to view this page.',
            'loginError' => 'Invalid Username or Password entered, please try again.'

        ));

    // only allow the login controllers only
    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('login','index');
        //allow access to currently logged in user to all programs
        $this->set('logged_in',$this->Auth->loggedIn());
        $this->set('current_user',$this->Auth->user());
    }




    public function isAuthorized($user) {

        return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: Put here Auth code from AppController.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a routing issue to me. There are a number of things which I would check.

1) Routing
Make sure that you have a route for `/checks/users/login`, which either resolves to your `UsersController::login()` method or redirects.

2) Auth setup
I would make sure that your login url specified in your Auth config specifically removes and prefix routing and plugin routing.

```
<?php
// If you were using 'admin' prefix routing
'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'instructors', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => false, 'plugin' => false)
```

3) Login method
Double check that you have a `UsersController::login()` method defined in your controller.

So in summary, I believe the issue is caused because you are in `/checks` routing, and you are trying to redirect the user to your login, but the `/checks` routing it sticking, meaning you're actually trying to redirect to `/checks/users/login` which doesn't exist, which is why a 404 is being generated.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean. As stated, I do not have a Userscontroller. Are you saying that Cakephp itself defaults to look for a Userscontroller and associated login method?